# MySQL Query: Consider A Value As Another Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do a query to count instances of different values and group them.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Type FROM Table GROUP BY Type
```

The values for Type can be C, V, and I - but I want it to consider any values that are I to be V.

So: 
    C = C
    V = V
    I = V

How can I do this in a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute a field that is equivelent.  The below `CASE` statement will take "I", make it "V" and leave everything else alone.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), CASE Type WHEN "I" THEN "V" ELSE Type END as NewType
FROM Table 
GROUP BY CASE Type WHEN "I" THEN "V" ELSE Type END
```